# Make windows maxmize past the panel

Tags: xfce4

I have a narrow panel in the corner with a clock and I want it to go over windows when maximizing.

[image: Screenshot]

It works if I make the panel hidden, but I don't want to do that. I can also manually drag the window to take up the full screen. If it isn't possible, any suggestions for a way to get a small clock in the corner without the panel?

Comment: Have you tried putting Chrome into Kiosk mode?